# Expanding Grids in the border in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, vector-grid

I have a shapefile of a city. My problem is that in the border, cells of the grids are not a complete square `(500*500 m)`, while I need them to be complete as I need their centroids too. As it is shown for example in the picture, all cell in the border should be complete( not limited to the city border). 
The steps I followed is that through fishnet I created grids and then clipped it to the city border. 
How I can fix this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of clipping, use **Select by Location** (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm). Use your grid as the **target** layer and your city layer as the **source** layer. Select features where they **intersect the source layer feature** (your city).

[image]